# How to implement fragment transaction in recycler view

Tags: c#, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I have been looking everywhere but i cannot find out how to do a fragment transaction when an item in a recycler view is clicked. So i was wandering if anyone knows how to do it in c#

Thanks

Recycler Adapter

```
class FavouritesPageAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    FavouritesFragment favFragment = new FavouritesFragment();
    private List<Favourites> mFavourites;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public FavouritesPageAdapter(List<Favourites> favourites, RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        mFavourites = favourites;
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mFavourites.Count; }
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        FavouritesViewHolder viewHolder = holder as FavouritesViewHolder;
        viewHolder.mCalcLabel.Text = mFavourites[position].CalcName;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View favouritesCard = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.favourites_cards, parent, false);

        TextView calcName = favouritesCard.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.calculatorLabel);

        FavouritesViewHolder view = new FavouritesViewHolder(favouritesCard) { mCalcLabel = calcName };

        return view;
    }

    public class FavouritesViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public View mMainView { get; set; }
        public TextView mCalcLabel { get; set; }

        public FavouritesViewHolder (View view) : base(view)
        {
        mMainView = view;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try something like creating adapter class & relevant holder class. If yes than edit your question & post that code so it would be easy to help you.

Comment: @Arvindraja code has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to open new `fragment` when user clicking on `recyclerView` item, try doing this in your `OnBindViewHolder` overridden method

```
public class FavouritesPageAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    FavouritesFragment favFragment = new FavouritesFragment();
    private List<Favourites> mFavourites;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    Activity _activity;

    public FavouritesPageAdapter(Activity activity, List<Favourites> favourites, RecyclerView recyclerView)
    {
        _activity=activity;
        mFavourites = favourites;
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    }
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        FavouritesViewHolder viewHolder = holder as FavouritesViewHolder;
        viewHolder.mCalcLabel.Text = mFavourites[position].CalcName;  
        var clickedItem = mFavourites[position];
        viewHolder.mMainView.click+=delegate
        {
            var objFrg = new MyFragment();
            var fragmentTx =_activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.crealtabcontent, objFrg, "MyFrgTag").AddToBackStack("myFrgBackStack");
            fragmentTx.Commit();            
        };
    }
}
```

Your fragment should look like this

```
public class MyFragment :Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{

}
```

For getting clicked item use `position` of `OnBindViewHolder` method. `_activity` is Activity you have to pass while calling your adapter like this

```
var fvrtAdapter = new FavouritesPageAdapter(this.Activity,favourites,recyclerView);
```

Comment: How can i find out which card has been clicked?

Comment: and the name _activity does not exist in current context

Comment: no errors but when i click on a card it doesnt do anything. The click function isnt being called